# Multiple !important ?!! Or something other?

Tags: css

I've problem  with my "JS-block validator". It should cover all the page and show this message, but in my project there shows also other files behind it. Can there be problem vith multiple `!important`?

`

```css
body:not(div#wojs){
 display:none !important;
}
#wojs{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 display:block !important;
 background-color: black;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
#wojs p {

    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: red;
    margin: 10% auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wojs">
 <p>JavaScript is disabled. Please, Allow it and refresh.</p>
</div>
```

`

Comment: It's always bad to have `!important` in your code. `files behind it` - if you are talking about `z-index` then there is no such rule in your code. Also it must be non-static positioned (relative, absolute or fixed)

Comment: It's doing something like this: https://snag.gy/x0ILeo.jpg